# How To Cut The Sprite Into An Irregularly Shape Using Cocos2d Game Engine?

Tags: opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone

How To Cut The Sprite Into An Irregularly Shape Using Cocos2d Game Engine?
I need to show the picture in an irregularly shape. Not only a rect shape or some regularly shape else,but any shape I want.
Is it any way to cut the sprite,texture or image into an irregularly shape?

As far as I know, there is no API to archive the purpose. Maybe OpenGL is the best way to do this,but I have no idea about how to archive it and make it into a CCSprite.

I hope someone can help me, because I really really need it.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I achieved this using this tutorial for Cocos2d 2.0

http://www.raywenderlich.com/4428/how-to-mask-a-sprite-with-cocos2d-2-0

If you are using 1.0 you can use this one

http://www.raywenderlich.com/4421/how-to-mask-a-sprite-with-cocos2d-1-0

Answer (score 0):

OpenGL can help you to achieve this. You need to triangulate desired shape, then fill it with texture of your sprite in you `draw` method

Comment: I am experiencing exactly the problem found on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11203127/cocos2d-v-2-0-masking-sprites-nightmare  do you care to answer that? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could do this type of thing using masking.  There is classes developed within the Cocos2D community already for this purpose.  Check out CCMask on [this Cocos2D thread](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/15890) or as mentioned by the article @Ben referenced you could do this using shaders in Cocos2D 2.0